# How to define and raise an event inside a static method (a PropertyChangedCallback)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events, custom-controls

I've defined an event in a custom control (`Field`) named `ValueChanged`.

```
public static event EventHandler<ValueChangedEventArgs> ValueChanged;
```

And a dependency property `Value`.

```
public string Value
{
    get => (string)GetValue(ValueProperty);
    set => SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Value), typeof(string), typeof(Field),
        new PropertyMetadata(OnValuePropertyChanged));
```

I need to fire my event when this value changes (if `FireValueChanged` is `true`).

```
private static void OnValuePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    bool fire = (bool)d.GetValue(FireValueChangedProperty);
    if (fire) ValueChanged?.Invoke(d, new ValueChangedEventArgs($"{e.NewValue}", $"{e.OldValue}"));
}
```

This is the `ValueChangedEventArgs` class

```
public class ValueChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string NewValue { get; }
    public string OldValue { get; }
    //Other calculated properties...

    public ValueChangedEventArgs(string newValue, string oldValue)
    {
        NewValue = newValue;
        OldValue = oldValue;
    }
}
```

But in my `main window` it says that

> cannot set the handler because the event is a static event.

And when I try to compile it says that

> the property 'ValueChanged' does not exist in the XML namespace 'clr-namespace: ...'.

If I try to set the event as non static, I cannot use it inside static `OnValuePropertyChanged` method.

Comment: Side note: be very careful using and subscribing to `static` events.  Great way to cause potential memory leaks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the control that the value was changed for in your `OnValuePropertyChanged` method like this (I've named the control class `MyControl`):

```
private static void OnValuePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    bool fire = (bool)d.GetValue(FireValueChangedProperty);
    var ctrl = (MyControl)d;
    if (fire) 
      ctrl.ValueChanged?.Invoke(d, new ValueChangedEventArgs($"{e.NewValue}", $"{e.OldValue}"));
}
```

Then you can remove the `static` and change the event to be an event on instance level:

```
public event EventHandler<ValueChangedEventArgs> ValueChanged;
```